# GeoServer, Raise java.io.IOException: Wrong magic number, expected 9994, got 51775770

Tags: geoserver, wfs-t

When I try to use transaction to insert or delete data to WFS service, I get this error. My geoservervr version is 2.21.0. I have checked and the shapefiles served by wfs are available normally and can be opened on arcmap. Moreover, through inspection, it is found that the magic number of this shp file is 9994, as shown in the following code:

```
$ od --endian big -t d4 -N4 v_00082_9c3754c882604122a4640d7d3f0ce110.shp
0000000        9994
0000004
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: please edit your question to show the error message from GeoServer and the XML you are sending to the server for the edit